# Date functions in Excel VBA only return 12/30/1899

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, i'm trying to read a date from a cell. The cell contains the date in the form "dd.mm.yyyy" (I'm in Germany). What I need specifically is the month. But when trying to read the month, Excel returns "12" every time. By trying Day() and Year(), I found out that the cell is recognised as blank cell and thus only returns the date of 12/30/1899, when obviously the date is entered correctly.

So this is what I'm trying to do which doesn't work (to put it as simply as possible):

ActiveSheet.Range("K2") = Month(B2)

And there you go, I get a "12" in K2, when the date is actually 02.02.2016.

Comment: Have you actually formatted the cell with "Format cells" to be a date?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that Excel stores dates as numbers, which are formatted to appear like dates in the current locale. The earliest date Excel can show is 1/1/1900, which is the number 1 in General format.

The date 15-July-2016 is the number 42566. That is the number of days since 1/1/1900.

To establish if a cell contains a real date, try formatting it with a different number format. Once you've established that it is a number and can be formatted as a date, you can move on to the next troubleshooting step.

You're not referencing cell B2 correctly.  Try

```
ActiveSheet.Range("K2") = Month(ActiveSheet.Range("B2"))
```

Comment: Right upon posting this, I noticed this. I've known about number formats etc., but something as stupid as this never even came to my mind. Thanks a lot and shame on me!

Comment: If that solved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [Tour]